# Restart not working in Trusty

Tags: 14.04, restart

I recently installed a 14.04 over an old 13.04 install. Everything is running smoothly, but for some odd reason, whenever I tell it to reboot (graphically, `reboot` or otherwise), it just shuts down without actually rebooting. I find this behavior rather annoying.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Very late comment, but restart is broken for me as well on 14.04, used to work on some older version. Also my laptop is a Latitude E5420, so this might be some bug very specific to Dell. Did you get it working in the mean time?

Comment: I did not get it working. I will say, though, that this is occurring on a Latitude E5420m (and not my new Latitude E6540), so it could even be related to the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to black list the MEI driver. In here

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

put this

```
# Make system reboot
blacklist mei
```

EDIT:
Also try

`sudo init 6`

or

in `/etc/default/grub`

set

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"`

then

`sudo update-grub`

UPDATE:

`reboot -f`

*OPTIONS -f, --force Does not invoke shutdown(8) and instead performs the actual action you would expect from the name.*

or

`sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: Didn't work. Other suggestions?

Comment: in `/etc/default/grub` set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"`
then
`sudo update-grub`

Comment: Separately check this command, `sudo init 6`

Comment: None of those worked either...

Comment: `reboot -f` OPTIONS
       -f, --force
              Does not invoke shutdown(8) and instead performs the actual action you would expect from the name.

Comment: Still same result...

Comment: `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: I already tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please inlcude your hardware details? I have found that such a problem occurred and mentioned in ["Running ‘sudo reboot’ causes shutdown with Intel C224 chipset"](http://www.gravitycomputing.co.nz/sudo-reboot-shutdown-intel-c224-chipset/) so it is said the problem was caused by buggy intel driver for that chipset. Also found this spell `/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
`

Comment: I'm running a Dell Latitiude E5420M with an Intel Moblie 4 Series Chipset (most of the port controllers read off as 82801, if that helps).

I should also note that reboot worked perfectly fine in my previous installation (13.04).

Comment: The dbus command didn't work either.

Comment: I also tried the KDE reboot command `qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 2 1`, to little success.